# Iterat array in JSON javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json

I got this JSON here with arrays.

```
chapter1 = '[\
{"name" : "Jeff","text":"Hi this is me.","image":"./images/char2.png","bgimg":"./images/bgimg/background1.jpg"}]';

choose1 = '[{"option1":"Come.","option2":"Everything right.","option3":"You are scared!"}]';

chapter1op1 = '[\
{"name" : "Marco","text":"Hi Jeff! It is me – Marco!","image":"./images/char2.png","bgimg":" "}]';
```

For example I iterat through it with a counter and display the information in my html.

```
var mydata = $.parseJSON(chapter1);
var bg ="url(" + mydata[counter].bgimg + ")";
    $("#main-screen-chapter1").css("background-image", bg);
```

At the end of the chapter1 array i display the choose1 array.

```
var decisionJson = $.parseJSON(choose1);
if (counter==mydata.length-1){

        $( "body").unbind( "click" );

        var op1;
        var op2;
        var op3;

        for (var i = 0; i < decisionJson.length; i++) {

            op1 = $('<tr/>');
            op2 = $('<tr/>');
            op3 = $('<tr/>');

            op1.append("<td>" + decisionJson[i].option1 + "</td>");
            op2.append("<td>" + decisionJson[i].option2 + "</td>");
            op3.append("<td>" + decisionJson[i].option3 + "</td>");

            $('#option1').append(op1);
            $('#option2').append(op2);
            $('#option3').append(op3);

            $('#option1').show();
            $('#option2').show();
            $('#option3').show();


        }
```

When I click on option1 i want to load the array chapter1op1 and run the script from the beginning again. 
I tried to overwrite the variable like this.

```
$( "#option1" ).click(function() {
 mydata = $.parseJSON(chapter1op1);
});
```

but it is not working.
Does somebody has an idea how to achieve this with an example?

Comment: What mean not working ?

Comment: it is not loading the array chapter1op1

Comment: For me , it is working perfectly: https://jsfiddle.net/muodLu0b/

Comment: Do you get an error in the developer tools console - it may be that your javascript is running before the appropriate element has been "loaded"

Comment: not in my project. i get the data from the array chapter1 and at the end i try to replace the var mydata with the new array chapter1op1 but the script doesnt run again

Comment: my guess is, wrap your code in `$(function() { ... your code ... });`

Comment: somehow i need to loop again with the new array somehow

Comment: @JaromandaX what do you mean?

Comment: read about jQuery `document ready`

Comment: @JaromandaX i tried it with document ready but it is not working
https://jsfiddle.net/ac7h44z1/

Comment: you need to parse the JSON strings to javascript arrays before using them like `decisionJson[i].option1` ... a string does not have an `option1`

Comment: @JaromandaX i know i just want to replace the var mydata and start the script from the beginning. In the console you can see that it just loads the chapter1 array and not the chapter1op1 array everytime i click